# Network status in Ionic-native, ionic2 error

Tags: ionic2

I am trying to use network api in ionic2, Ionic-native docs example is not working:
My code is:

```
import { Network } from 'ionic-native';

networkType:string;
constructor() {
    // watch network for a connection
    let connectSubscription = Network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
      this.networkType = Network.type;
    });    
  }
```

I am getting error `Property 'type' does not exist on type 'typeof Network'.` If any one has successfully used Ionic-native in ionic2, please help.

I have done `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information`

Comment: I had this until I updated to the latest version of Ionic-Native (2.2.16).  My network plugin is version 1.3.1.  Having said that, I am having trouble getting the onConnect subscription to fire.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
this.networkType = Network.connection;
```

By looking at the source code of network.d.ts I found this:

```
 * @advanced
 * The `connection` property will return one of the following connection types: `unknown`, `ethernet`, `wifi`, `2g`, `3g`, `4g`, `cellular`, `none`
 */
export declare class Network {
    /**
     * Return the network connection type
     */
    static connection: string;
    /**
     * Get notified when the device goes offline
     * @returns {Observable<any>} Returns an observable.
     */
    static onDisconnect(): Observable<any>;
    /**
     * Get notified when the device goes online
     * @returns {Observable<any>} Returns an observable.
     */
    static onConnect(): Observable<any>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem for onConnect() alone and this solution helped me get it working,

Update your ionic-native to latest version and it should work fine then

Run `npm rm --save ionic native` and then `npm install --save ionic-native@latest`